# Merging 2 sorted arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to merge 2 sorted arrays where `n` is the number of elements in `nums2` and `m` are the number of elements in `nums1`.

https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-sorted-array/description/

Why's my solution incorrect?

```
public void merge(int[] nums1, int m, int[] nums2, int n) {
    int[] a = new int[m + n];
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;

    while(i < nums1.length && j < nums2.length) {
        if(nums1[i] < nums2[j]) {
            a[k] = nums1[i];
            i++;
            k++;  
        }

        else {
            a[k] = nums2[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why *is* your code incorrect? Are you getting an error? Not the desired output?

Comment: Why do you need `m` and `n` if you're using the length?

Comment: @GBlodgett I've provided a link to the problem I'm doing on leet code

Comment: @alfasin I've provided a link to the problem I'm doing on leet code

Comment: Pay attention to the problem definition: **..."merge nums2 into nums1 as one sorted array."**

Answer (score 3):

After `while` is terminated, one list has remaining elements. Thus, you check which list is not empty and append them at the end of new list.

Comment: The simple way to do it is just copy the remaining elements from both arrays. For one array there will be 0 elements to copy, that’s OK.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, while (i < nums1.length && j < nums2.length) will bail when one of those conditions are met, meaning the other array can't finish.

Answer (score -1):

You should insert remaining elements after that the condition of while is satisfied. You can see the follow pseudocode of a generic merge in case of sets. You can easily arrange to your arrays.

Algorithm genericMerge (A, B) :

```
S <- empty set
while !A.isEmpty() and !B.isEmpty() do
  a <- A.first().element()
  b <- B.first().element()

  if a < b
    a.isLess(a, S)
    A.remove(A.first())
  else if a > b
    b.isLess(b, S)
    B.remove(B.first())
  else
    a.areBothEqual (a, S)
    A.remove(A.first())
    B.remove(B.first())

while !A.isEmpty() do
   a <- A.first().element()
   a.isLess(a, S)
   A.remove(A.first())

while !B.isEmpty() do
   b <- B.first().element()
   b.isLess(b, S)
   B.remove(B.first())
return S
```

Comment: That is just so very wrong. 1) It's not Java. 2) What is `isless()` and `areBothEqual` supposed to be doing? 3) Why call `remove` when A and B should remain unmodified? 4) Where are values added to `S`? 5) Question is about Java arrays, while this "algorithm" is working on collections. --- No useful.

Comment: It isn't my intention to post a wrong answer. I thought that a similar idea on different data structures can be useful, but apparently it doesn't work like that.